# Split string with various delimiters while keeping delimiters

Tags: javascript, string, split

I have the following string:

```
"dogs@cats^horses^fish!birds"
```

How can I get the following array back?

```
['dogs','@cats','^horses','^fish','!birds']
```

Essentially I am trying to split the string while keeping the delimeters.  I've tried `string.match` with no avail.

Comment: What code did you have?

Comment: @SmokeyPHP and downvoters: Code is not always necessary. There are some cases where it's a problem where either you know the solution, or you don't, and adding in some code isn't going to change much. There's a meta post about this somewhere that i can't find right now.

Comment: @Scimonster No it's not, but proof that you've tried mostly is. I didn't downvote, but as the OP had said they'd already tried `string.match` it's interesting to know what they had tried so that we can tell them where they went wrong rather then handing over a full solution. They might have been so close!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming those are your only separators then you can do this:

```
var string = "dogs@cats^horses^fish!birds";
string.replace(/(@|\^|!)/g, '|$1').split('|');
```

We basically add our own separator, in this case `|` and split it based on that.

Comment: Very nice and clean solution!!

Comment: @Cmag I think you should be thanking Samer... just saying :p (no offense to silentw of course!)

Answer (score 2):

This does what you want:

```
str.match(/((^|[^\w])\w+)/g)
```

Without more test cases though, it's hard to say how reliable it would be.

This is also assuming a large set of possible delimiters. If it's a small fixed amount, Samer's solution would be a good way to go